# How to fix "unable to locate..." error when installing ubuntu package mssql-tool

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install mssql-tool package for php by executing following command:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
exit
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
```

I receive to types of errors:

1. Duplicates in the source list
2. Not locatable package mssql-tools

I am wondering now, if the second error is caused by the first one and how to fix the first one?

Specification of server: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-042stab120.20 x86_64).

```
root:~# sudo su
root:~# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.li                                                                                                                     st > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0    483      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   481
root:~# exit
exit
root:~# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in                                                                                                                      /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.                                                                                                                     list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /e                                                                                                                     tc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.li                                                                                                                     st:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times i                                                                                                                     n /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-releas                                                                                                                     e.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in                                                                                                                      /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.li                                                                                                                     st:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /e                                                                                                                     tc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list                                                                                                                     :1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times i                                                                                                                     n /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.                                                                                                                     list:1
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools
```

If I include apt-get update in the commands, the system gets stuck by 0% Working:

```
root:~# sudo su
root:~# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0    502      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   506
root:~# exit
exit
root:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA_17.5.3 xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP56_17 xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP70_17 xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP71_17 xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/NGINX17 xenial InRelease
0% [Working]
```

Comment: You forgot to run `apt-get update` to fetch info about packages in the repository you just added. For the warnings, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m

Comment: Interestingly, including apt-get update does not work. I edited my entry above and included additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this 'W: Target Packages' problem, Try this commants,

```
1) sudo apt install python3-apt
2) sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidfoerster/apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries/master/apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
3) sudo chmod +x apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
4) sudo ./apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
```